# "locate: illegal option --b" in HELM locate mode

Tags: spacemacs

Here is the screenshot

[image]

The mode is triggered by `SPC-f-L` .

I am using OSX and locate is already installed.

How can I solve this issue? Install a different version of locate or Change the behaviour of the mode?

Answer (score 1):

according to the output of locate, it does not know the option `-b`, so you need to customize helm-locate (`M-x customize-group helm-locate`) and remove the option -b from the invocation of it („helm locate command”).  Don't forget to press „save and apply” further up to make the change permanent.

try this invocation if you still have problems: `locate %s -e -A --regex %s`

Comment: From ```helm-locate-command``` documentation: Note that the "-b" option is added automatically by helm when var ‘helm-locate-fuzzy-match’ is non-nil and switching back from multimatch to fuzzy matching (this is done automatically when a space is detected in pattern). I tried to customise the ```helm-locate-command``` but still getting the errors as the "-b" option is always added automatically :-(